# Nested tableview or Custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, nested-table

I have to design a table view which loads data dynamically. Now the data source is an array of values for a particular row. Naturally, I have to use a second table view (nested one) to show the same. The problem is there are a lot of customization in both the table views like checkbox button, border around the rows etc. (refer the image)
The data inside the nested tableview is also loaded dynamically hence the rows will be created dynamically. **My question here is (after looking at the UI) what will be the right approach for the same? A nested table view or a custom UI view?** If nested table view any good resources available for the same? P.S - The data is loaded dynamically.

[image]

Comment: you want to show cell description on cell tap?

Comment: No @TusharSharma. The description is always visible

Comment: you should create expandable table view for this .It will be much better solution then showing it this way.

Comment: @tusha Thats not how the UI designer wants :(

Comment: what you actually want like you have a table view with 10 rows with all that data then where do you want to show another table ?? when is it required??